# TDD: Test member initialization deterministically, given undefined behavior in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, undefined-behavior, googletest

**Note:** I know that `active_` could be "anything" in my example. This is not what this question is about. It's about making an "undefined value" reliably fail a unit test.

**Edit:** Changed from "no constructor" to "empty constructor".

I'm working on a C++ class and I'm using TDD. Now I want to ensure that a `bool` class member is initialized properly - that a value is assigned to it in the constructor. So I write the following test (using the Google Mock/Google Test framework):

```
TEST(MyClass, isNotActiveUponCreation) {
    MyClass my;
    ASSERT_FALSE(my.isActive());
}
```

And the following class definition:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // Note: Constructor doesn't initialize active_
    MyClass() {}

    bool isActive() const { return active_; }
private:
    bool active_;
};
```

*The problem:* On my machine, this test currently always passes, even though `active_` is never initialized. Now we know that the value of `active_` is undefined, since it's a primitive type and never initialized. So in theory, it might be `true` at some point, but in the end, *it's impossible to know*. Bottom line is, I cannot reliably test for missing initialization using this approach.

Does anybody have an idea how I might test this situation in a way that's deterministic and repeatable? Or do I have to live with it, omit this kind of test and hope that I'll never forget to initialize a boolean member, or that other tests will always catch resulting defects?

Comment: Initialize the variable in the constructor, otherwise it could be set to anything.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes I know. But what I want is to ensure the constructor sets it - using TDD. So I'm looking for a way for my test to reliably fail in case `active_` is "set to anything". I added a note to make that clearer.

Comment: Just a thought, not a real answer: What if you create an std::vector containing, say, 100 MyClass objects. Is `active_` false for each object then?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Assuming `vector<MyClass> v(100)`, and if `MyClass` has current form without user-provided default constructor, then yes, all the vector's elements are value-initialized, which value-initializes the data members, which for `bool` means zero-initialization, which sets it to `false`.

Comment: Let's say `MyClass` has a constructor, but it doesn't initialize `active_`..

Comment: @lethal-guitar:Going back to your original problem. Why resort to testing when it can be accomplished through design? Let the contructor take a bool as an argument to assign the bool member. This is particularly useful when MyClass is a base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading TobiMcNamobi's answer, I remembered [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) and got an idea how to solve my problem. The following test reliably fails unless I initialize `active_` in the constructor:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
public:
    // Note: Constructor doesn't initialize active_
    MyClass() {}

    bool isActive() const { return active_; }
private:
    bool active_;
};

TEST(MyClass, isNotActiveUponCreation) {
    // Memory with well-known content
    std::vector<char> preFilledMemory(sizeof(MyClass), 1);

    // Create a MyClass object in that memory area using placement new
    auto* myObject = new(preFilledMemory.data()) MyClass();


    ASSERT_FALSE(myObject->isActive());
    myObject->~MyClass();
}
```

Now I'll admit that this test is not the most readable one, and likely not immediately clear at first sight, but it works reliably and independent of any 3rd-party tools like valgrind. Is it worth the additional effort? I'm not sure. It heavily depends on `MyClass` internals, which will make it very brittle. Anyway, it is one way to test for correctly initialized objects in C++..

Comment: Interesting, but you are relying on initializing the memory to the wrong value which I think would impractical in the general case. Interesting question anyway. Much more than I first thought I must admit!

Comment: +1. Maybe initializing to `(char)1` is still a bit insecure. Maybe it should be `(unsigned char)-1` so that every bit is 1. But that's details. Great answer anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Such kind of problems is actually quite easy to unit tests, once you have unit tests in place.

Just run unit tests under memory checker (valgrind on linux, not sure what is used on windows).

Instead of creating gtest executable, I created a simple example :

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    // Note: no constructor

    bool isActive() const { return active_; }
private:
    bool active_;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c;  // line 17

    std::cout << c.isActive() << std::endl;
}
```

Running it under valgrind, I got next output (trimmed unneeded lines) :

```
==9217== 
==9217== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
.....
==9217==    by 0x40094F: main (garbage.cpp:17)
```

When you execute your unit tests with valgrind, you will get all kind of problems related to memory access. You will also get backtraces.

Comment: I would like to see an answer that is pure TDD and doesn't rely on any tool like valgrind.

Comment: That sounds promising, even though it adds some complexity. Do you know an easy way to automate this? Ideally, I'd like to be able to run such a check from my gtest test suite.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I would also like such tool, but it doesn't exist. Maybe some static code checkers, but those are not in spirits of TDD

Comment: @lethal-guitar On linux, you can create a script which builds unit tests, and execute them using valgrind. Then in script set all options.

Answer (score 1):

My little test:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    // Note: Constructor doesn't initialize active_
    MyClass() {}

    bool isActive() const { return active_; }
private:
    bool active_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<MyClass> vec(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (vec[i].isActive() ? "1" : "0");
    }

    return system("pause");
}
```

So what happens when this is executed (compiled with VS2012)?

Debug configuration: A thousand 1's are written.

Release config: A thousand 0's are written. I raised the iteration count to 100,000 and got a hundred-thousand 0's ... no wait the first few numbers were 10101110000000... and there! Somewhere in between another sequence like this is hidden.

What does this mean? The result was more or less expected. You cannot predict how a single uninitialized bit is set. What you want to do here is initialize some space in memory and create an object just there as if that memory had not initialized before.

So until I'm proven wrong: **You cannot unit-test it**.

Unless you use a tool (e.g. valgrind, see other answer).

TDD is great I think but it has its limits of course. I'd just initialize the flag and continue the red-green-refactor cycle.

Comment: "you want to ... initialize some space in memory and create an object just there ..." - shouldn't that be possible with placement new?

Comment: @lethal-guitar The problem is that if you call `new` you don't know the address where the memory will be allocated in the first place. Consider the following sentence: "Create a new object of Myclass *somewhere* and initialize everything that is uninitialized with this and that." Of course you can say "Give me the address of object x (of type Myclass or whatever) and now allocat new memory for object y" but how can you controll that y is allocated at the position of x? I don't know. But if I get to know, I will edit or delete this answer.

Comment: C++ has a language feature called [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html). It allows you to "place" an object into memory you allocated - so you could fill a buffer with all 1s, place your object there and then test. I'll give it a go and write my own answer if it works..

Answer (score 1):

A TDD test should exercise behavior rather than implementation details.  Tests for constructor initialization, setter initialization, etc. depend on a specific implementation and will be fragile if the implementation is refactored.

Comment: Well, but the test "isNotActiveUponCreation" tests only externally visible behavior as part of the class' interface, right? The problem is that "not initialized" means "arbitrary value" in C++, whereas it doesn't in other languages (like Java, Python) where you can be sure that your values will be `null` or similar if you don't initialize them

Comment: You're definitely right about the test in my own answer, though - it will break as soon as `MyClass` doesn't use a `bool` member anymore to determine if it's "active".

Comment: In TDD, the test comes first and is written to describe some small item of desired domain behavior.  'isNotActiveUponCreation' is not describing domain behavior, it's describing implementation details: we'll have a class, it'll have an 'active' property, etc.  The decision to have a class with an 'active' property is driven by making a failing test pass for some item of domain behavior. I would look to static code analysis tools to detect uninitialized members rather than unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to unit test for undefined behavior which is pointless as all results would obviously need to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your unit test suite with [MemorySanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html), then any reads from uninitialized memory should cause the tests to fail.